# Including extremities in interval of increasing functions

Tags: calculus

Isn't it weird to say that $y = x^2$ is a decreasing function in $(-\infty, 0]$ and increasing in $[0, \infty)$.  It should be decreasing in $(-\infty, 0)$ and increasing in $(\infty,0)$.

Some answers on some sites try to explain this by proposing the conventions set for increasing and strictly increasing....but the whole point is what's the need of such conventions?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.   $f(x) > f(0)$ whenever $x < 0$ and that $f(0) < f(x)$ whenever $x > 0$.  Why do you think we should not include the endpoints of the intervals?  What is your definition of increasing on an interval? decreasing on an interval?

Comment: Why do you think the function is not increasing on $[0,\infty)$? What is "weird" about saying that?

Comment: As rate of change of function is zero at x=0...so should be decreasing for all x <0  and increasing  for all x> 0

Comment: How about $y=x^3$? Would you agree that it is an increasing function on the whole of the real line? Drawing the graph of the function makes it obvious it is increasing. (While its derivative at $x=0$ is $0$) In any case you should follow the definitions. The definition of a function $f(x)$ increasing in $[a,b]$ is that for any two points $x<y$ in $[a,b]$ we have $f(x)<f(y)$. This is satisfied by $y=x^3$ and it is also satisfied by $y=x^2$ in $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Should be decreasing in ( - inf, 0) and increasing  in ( 0, inf)

Comment: Sir , the case of x^3 is different, even there if we say increasing interval is (  -inf, 0) U ( 0 , inf) that would not be wrong mathematically. BUT asking a student about increasing interval of a function like x^2 or cubic with 3 zeroes and asking him to choose between  ( a, b) and [a, b] is weird... every proposed definition have some basis. Can you please tell me why such an assumption or definition has been proposed?

Answer (score 0):

A function is said to be *increasing* on an interval $I$ if for each $x_1, x_2 \in I$ with $x_1 < x_2$, $f(x_1) \leq f(x_2)$.  It is said to be *strictly increasing* on an interval $I$ if for each $x_1, x_2 \in I$ with $x_1 < x_2$, $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$.

Under this definition, the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^2$ is both increasing and strictly increasing on the interval $[0, \infty)$ since whenever $x_1, x_2 \in [0, \infty)$ with $x_1 < x_2$,
$$f(x_2) - f(x_1) = (x_2)^2 - (x_1)^2 = (x_2 - x_1)(x_2 + x_1) > 0$$
since it is a product of two positive number.  In particular, if $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 > 0$, we have
$$f(x_2)^2 - f(0) = (x_2)^2 - (x_1)^2 = (x_2)^2 - 0^2 > 0$$

A function is said to be *decreasing* on an interval $I$ if for each $x_1, x_2 \in I$ with $x_1 < x_2$, $f(x_1) \geq f(x_2)$.  It is said to be *strictly decreasing* on an interval $I$ if for each $x_1, x_2 \in I$ with $x_1 < x_2$, $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$.

Under this definition, the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^2$ is both decreasing and strictly decreasing on the interval $(-\infty, 0]$ since whenever $x_1, x_2 \in (-\infty, 0]$ with $x_1 < x_2$,
$$f(x_2) - f(x_1) = (x_2)^2 - (x_1)^2 = (x_2 - x_1)(x_2 + x_1) < 0 $$
since it is a product of a positive number $x_2 - x_1$ and a negative number $x_2 + x_1$.  In particular, if $x_1 < 0$ and $x_2 = 0$, we have
$$f(x_2) - f(x_1) = (x_2)^2 - (x_1)^2 = 0^2 - (x_1)^2 < 0$$

Notice that the definition of whether a function is increasing depends on comparing the values of a function at distinct points.  The source of your confusion seems to be that the derivative of a function may be zero at a particular point of the interval, but that does tell you what is happening at surrounding points.

The derivative of the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^2$ is zero at the point $0$, where the function has a relative minimum since it is continuous, decreasing from $(-\infty, 0]$, and increasing from $[0, \infty)$.

On the other hand, the function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) = x^3$ is zero at the point $0$, but the function is increasing on $(-\infty, \infty)$ since the function is continuous and whenever $x_1 < x_2$,
$$f(x_2) - f(x_1) = (x_2)^3 - (x_1)^3 = (x_2 - x_1)[(x_2)^2 + x_1x_2 + (x_1)^2] > 0$$
since it is a product of positive numbers.